# How to get variable values in triggered alert in AWS ElasticSearch Service?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm trying to post detailed message on Slack from AWS ElasticSearchService Monitor Alert Trigger. I've tried to use variables as in description 
https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/monitors/

Alerts are getting triggered and posted on Slack, but most of variables are empty, when I try to use them in action. I get information only from `ctx.trigger.name`, `ctx.periodStart`, `ctx.periodEnd`. Variables like `ctx.trigger.condition`, `ctx.results[0]`, `ctx.error`, `ctx.results[0].hits.total` are empty, while the docs are saying `ctx.error` will be filled, if `ctx.results[0]` is empty.

How do I get more data? Is my query limiting it somehow?

My Monitor extraction query is following:

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                    "from": "now-1m",
                                    "to": null,
                                    "include_lower": true,
                                    "include_upper": true,
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "status": {
                                    "query": "200",
                                    "operator": "OR",
                                    "prefix_length": 0,
                                    "max_expansions": 50,
                                    "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                                    "lenient": false,
                                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                                    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                    "boost": 1
                }
            },
            "boost": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trigger syntax uses Moustache templates ([man page](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)), which is not comprehensive. The trick is to loop through the results and refer to variables like this:

```
- Total hits: {{#ctx.results}}{{#hits}}{{total}}{{/hits}}{{/ctx.results}}
- Period start: {{ctx.periodStart}}
- Period end: {{ctx.periodEnd}}
- HTTP errors:
  {{#ctx.results}}
      {{#hits}}
          {{#hits}}
              {{#_source}} ip:{{ip}} status: {{status}} : {{error.message}} at path: {{path}} {{/_source}}
          {{/hits}}
      {{/hits}}
  {{/ctx.results}}
```